# Adding objects to a fixed Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Up till now I've been using ArrayLists. I've used Arrays once but it was used differently then how I'm suppose to now. I currently have a class called `Member` and it looks something like this:

```
public class Member
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int monthJoined;
    private int yearJoined;
}
```

Of course this class has accessor/ mutator methods and constructors below.

Now I have to make a class called **Club** which can hold a fixed number of members stored in an Member[] Array. (The fixed number can be any number) So at this point I'm wondering what the variable would look like. Also this class will need a method titled **public void join(Member member)** which adds a member to the club, the new members will be added to the first null index in the Array.

I know how this would work with an ArrayList but not with an array. So given the class **Club** what would the variable and the method look like?

Comment: What is wrong with ArrayLists?

Comment: Just access your array using `[]` with index.

Comment: Nothings wrong with arraylist but for this assignment in particular my instructor has told us specifically to use Array. sorry I should've mentioned that

Comment: You would declare your array like normal, `Member[] members = new Member[numElements]`.  Be aware though that each element will hold the value `null` until it is filled.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly discourage you from using an array when an `ArrayList` would do the job better. In general, in Java, collections (e.g. an `ArrayList`) are preferred to an array, unless some specific circumstances dictate otherwise.

The main disadvantage of arrays is that their size must be fixed at the time of initialization and that remains so as long as the reference to the array remains available. Thus, if your `Club` may contain `1000` members in next 5 years, you will need to allocate for those `1000` members right now. The moment a 1001st member joins, you have to allocate a new and improved array, copy all existing members and then use the new array. This and more is done by an `ArrayList` transparently.

Having said that, using the array itself should be straightforward:

```
class Club {
    //thread unsafe 
    private Member[] members;
    private int nCurrentMembers = 0;

    Club(int initialCapacity) {
        //validate initialCapacity
        members = new Member[initialCapacity];
    }

    public boolean join(Member m) {
        //validate m
        if (nCurrentMembers == members.length) {
            members = Arrays.copyOf(members, members.length + 100);
        }
        members[nCurrentMembers++] = m;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean leave(Member m) {
        // homework :-)
        return true;
    }
}
```